# Does the verb eruo mean to rescue or deliver?

Tags: vulgata, bible

I'm reading Psalm 42 verse 1 from the Vulgate Bible. Here is the translation on vulgata.net:

> Psalmus 42:1 Psalmus David. Judica me, Deus, et discerne causam meam de gente non
> sancta, ab homine iniquo et doloso erue me.
>
> A psalm for David. Judge me, O God, and distinguish my cause from the
> nation that is not holy: deliver me from the unjust and deceitful man.

The text translates eruo as "deliver". I'm curious about the word "eruo". Does it often get translated as rescue or deliver? I looked it up on Lewis & Short and on Wiktionary, but that sense of the word isn't readily apparent in these dictionaries.

The word "deliver" appears often in the Bible, and I'm curious why the translator chose the verb "eruo" for this meaning. What other Latin words can be used for the meaning of rescue or deliver, and how often is "eruo" chosen for this meaning?

Answer (score 8):

I'd say in this instance "extricate" and "set free" are performing the same action: if you are extricated from your enemies, you are liberated from them.

This usage for *eruo* is under the figurative section in Lewis and Short. Note in particular this part:

> 1. To rescue, release: “propter difficultatem pecuniariam, qua erui nusquam nisi ex privatorum bonis posset,” Cic. Att. 10, 14, 1.—